# How to get the time zone from latitude and longitude coordinates with BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp, timezone, coordinates

Given latitudes and longitudes, how can I know what time zone is in effect in that location **with BigQuery**?

Suppose I have a table with 100 coordinates:

```
SELECT (RAND()-0.5)*90 as latitude, (RAND()-0.5)*180 as longitude FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100))
```

| Row | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -24.66121614027115 | 31.92125752510383 |
| 2 | -17.060823106878654 | 30.070053747514052 |
| 3 | 1.5425276266633903 | 32.30384245018918 |

I search the easiest way to get:

| timezone |
| --- |
| Africa/Maputo |
| Africa/Harare |
| Africa/Kampala |

Comment: do u want SQL only solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by uploading time zone polygon boundaries.

E.g. you can get them from here https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder. This project offers shapefile and geojson file formats, you'll need to convert to one of the formats supported by BigQuery, e.g. new-line-delimited geojson, or CSV, and upload to BigQuery. Open source [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) tool can do this, as well as many proprietary tools.

Once you have the data in BigQuery, you can join the locations with time zone polygons, like

```sql
WITH points AS (
  SELECT (RAND()-0.5)*90 as latitude, (RAND()-0.5)*180 as longitude 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100))
)
SELECT * FROM points p CROSS JOIN time_zones tz
ON ST_Intersects(ST_GeogPoint(p.longitude, p.latitude), tz.geometry)
```

Comment: Thanks @michael ! The uploading of time zone boundaries in BigQuery is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480839/how-to-get-time-zone-boundaries-in-bigquery).