# How to get time zone boundaries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp, timezone, gis

Giving the following GCP services:

- BigQuery
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Shell

What is the easiest way to create a BigQuery table with the following 2-columns structure ?

| Column | Description | Type | Primary key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tzid | Time zone identifier | STRING | x |
| bndr | Boundaries | GEOGRAPHY |  |

For example:

| tzid | bndr |
| --- | --- |
| Africa/Abidjan | POLYGON((-5.440683 4.896553, -5.303699 4.912035, -5.183637 4.923927, ...)) |
| Africa/Accra | POLYGON((-0.136231 11.13951, -0.15175 11.142384, -0.161168 11.14698, ...)) |
| Pacific/Wallis | MULTIPOLYGON(((-178.350043 -14.384951, -178.344628 -14.394109, ...))) |

Comment: Hi.  So far, the only discernible question you've asked is how to access a table, which would only be answerable as, "the same way you access any other table."   Please clarify your question.  Are you trying to write a query? Are you needing help with connecting to a database?  What language/platform are you using to access? etc.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, might be relevant for you is [the Google time zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview), or the [timezone boundary builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) project (or one of its lookup libraries).

Comment: Hi @MattJohnson-Pint, I replaced "access" by "create" to be more acurate ;-)

Answer (score 5):

1. Download and unzip `timezones.geojson.zip` from @evan-siroky [repository](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder/releases) on your computer.
   Coordinates are structured as follows (**geojson** format):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features":
  [
   {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":
     {
      "tzid":"Africa/Abidjan"
     },
     "geometry":
     {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[-5.440683,4.896553],[-5.303699,4.912035], ...]]]
     }
   },
   {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties": ...
   }
  ]
}
```

BigQuery does not accept **geojson** but **jsonl** (new line delimited json) format to load tables. Steps 3 to 5 aim to convert to **jsonl** format.

2. Upload the file `timezones_geojson.json` to Cloud Storage `gs://your-bucket/`.
3. Move the file in the Cloud Shell Virtual Machine

```
gsutil mv gs://your-bucket/timezones_geojson.json .
```

4. Parse the file timezones_geojson.json, filter on "features" and return one line per element (see [jq command](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```
cat timezones_geojson.json | jq -c ".features[]" > timezones_jsonl.json
```

The previous format will be transformed to:

```
{
 "type":"Feature",
 "properties":
 {
  "tzid":"Africa/Abidjan"
 },
 "geometry":
 {
  "type":"Polygon",
  "coordinates":[[[-5.440683,4.896553],[-5.303699,4.912035], ... ]]]
 }
}
{
 "type":"Feature",
 "properties":...
 "geometry":...
}
```

5. Move the **jsonl** on Cloud Storage

```
gsutil mv timezones_jsonl.json gs://your-bucket/
```

6. Load the **jsonl** to BigQuery

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --json_extension=GEOJSON your_dataset.timezones gs://your-bucket/timezones_jsonl.json
```